# Is there a way in javascript to make the page jump to a specific location

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript to make the page jump to a specific location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569329/javascript-to-make-the-page-jump-to-a-specific-location)

Is there a way in javascript to make the page jump to a specific location on the page, such as

```
  <span id='jump_to_this_location'></span>
```

must be javascript or jquery, I don't want to reload the page.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question twice? The answers in the other question already address this, and don't reload the page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569329/javascript-to-make-the-page-jump-to-a-specific-location

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a named anchor (like `<a name="jump_here"></a>`), and then you can navigate to it using Javascript: `window.location.hash = "jump_here";`

Answer (score 0):

tell me if this works for you, without re-loading the page.

```
top!

<script>
window.location.hash = "jump_here";
</script>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<a name="jump_here"></a>
bottom!
```