# How can I reveal a div at the bottom of a page, then jump to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, progressive-enhancement

I'm building a [progressively-enhanced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement), [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)ed web application that features [task-centric help](http://www.cfug-md.org/meetings/JeromyFrench_TaskCentricHelpSystems.ppt) on every page. The help area div (`id="help_area"`) loads in a hidden state; generally when the user clicks on the "help" button (`a id="nav_help_button"`), the main content div condenses from span12 to span9, and the help area is revealed as a span3. This works well.

Because I want to support mobile and tablet, I'm using Bootstrap's responsive scaffolding. So *if you are viewing the page on a narrow viewport*, clicking on the help button "reveals" the hidden help area at the bottom of the page‡. I'm trying to use jQuery's `.slideToggle()`'s callback method to execute JavaScript (`window.location.hash = "help_area";`) that "jumps to" the help area after it is revealed, but having no luck with the jumping (it doesn't error; it just doesn't move browser focus to the help area).

**How can I reveal a div at the bottom of a page, then jump to it?** I'm also using preventDefault so the browser won't try to jump to the internal link before the target is revealed. Could that be the conflict?

Here's the relevant ECMA script:

```
$('#nav_help_button').click(function(event) {
    "use strict"; //let's avoid tom-foolery in this function
    event.preventDefault(); //don't let a tag try to jump us to #help_area before we reveal it
    //adjust spans of main block and help area, set aria-hidden attribute on help block to help screen-readers
    if ( $('#help_area').attr('aria-hidden')==='true' ) {
        $('#content_container.span12').switchClass('span12', 'span9', 300);
        $('#help_area').delay(300).slideToggle(300, function() { window.location.hash = "help_area"; }).attr('aria-hidden', 'false');   
    }
    else {
        $('#help_area').slideToggle(300).attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
        $('#content_container.span9').delay(300).switchClass('span9', 'span12', 300);
    }
});
```

I have also set up [a JSFiddle that illustrates the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/HdCbu/). 
To duplicate

1. open http://fiddle.jshell.net/jhfrench/HdCbu/7/show
2. then resize that browser window until "PTO, AIT Life, Hours Worked", etc stacks on top of each other
3. click on the button in the upper-right corner (the one with three white horizontal bars) to reveal the nav menu
4. click on the blue "help" button to execute the reveal/jump-to.

‡ As the right-most div, everything to the left of it gets stacked on top, so the newly "revealed" help area is generally below the visible portion of the page.

Related:

- [Javascript to make the page jump to a specific location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569329/javascript-to-make-the-page-jump-to-a-specific-location)
- http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/
- http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: Offtopic: Please! Please, don't use touchstart in navigations!

Comment: Could you try `$("#help_area").focus();` ?

Comment: Appears to work fine in Chrome. The blue help box was revealed at the bottom, and the browser jumped down to it.

Comment: How embarrassing...it *is* working (even on my Android). I think @WillNelson is right about  http://fiddle.jshell.net/jhfrench/HdCbu/7/show vs  http://fiddle.jshell.net/jhfrench/HdCbu/7/show/#help_area and I'll look into how to compensate for that. Thanks for taking the time everyone...

Comment: @yckart: "touchstart"? Am I (is bootstrap) using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSFiddle  does  jump when I do exactly as you say (steps 1-4) for my browser, which is Chrome 24. What's your browser?

But perhaps this is your problem. If I navigate to http://fiddle.jshell.net/jhfrench/HdCbu/7/show/#help_area (note the appended hash tag) and perform your steps 1-4, my browser does NOT jump. Note that when you first navigate to that URL, there is no visible #help_area. Thus, the URL you're navigating to specifies a hash tag that's invisible. Perhaps the browser is a bit confused by this and just leaves the #help_area hash tag in a bad state. It won't allow scrolling to it from then on, even after it becomes visible. Speculation, but I hope it's helpful!

Comment: Waterfox 18.0.1 does it anyway.

Comment: I just tried on Waterfox 18.0.1 on Windows 7 and it worked fine for me. Be very careful about two things. First, navigate to the URL without the #help_area hash tag. Second, observe that if you repeatedly click the "Help" button, it will only scroll <em> every other time </em>. There's nothing mysterious about this. The Help button toggles the visibility of the #help_area div. When it's disappearing, the line 'window.location.hash = "help_area"' does nothing. Click it again, making the div appear, and it jumps properly. Whether the Help button should toggle the help area is another matter!